# Redirect with additional variables

Tags: python, django

I have view which in some cases redirects user to another addres.
How can I redirect user, with additional variables (not GET, beacause that variable can be long text)?
Currently I'm using HttpResponseRedirect.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

You can't force a POST on redirect. Perhaps your best option is to store the variables in `request.session`, and then check for the presence of these variables in the view handler for the redirected URL.

Here's some more info on [sessions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#topics-http-sessions).